# Do Ignis' stats change at a particular point in the story?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

At I think the end of Ch.9, Ignis came back from a scripted separation of the party blinded.

That quite tanky melee fighter seems now to just get one shotted every fight.

Returned before Ch.9 to farm, and he seems back to being a worthwile party member.

Does Ignis' blindness change any of his stats? Or am I imagining the difference before/after Ch.9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Ignis does not get weaker. The only time he is impaired is in the mines, where he struggles to keep up and Gladiolus yells at you if you leave him too far behind.

After that point, Ignis learns to develop superhuman hearing to compensate for his lack of sight and he is no worse a fighter for it.